# How to find out if an object is of <type> or a decendant of <type>

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have the following code:

```
foreach (var control in this.Controls)
{

}
```

I want to do something like `control.Hide()` in there.  But the items in the `this.Controls` collection are not of type `Control` (they are `Object`).

I can't seem to remember the safe way to cast this to call hide if it is really of type `Control` and do nothing otherwise.  (I am a transplanted delphi programmer and I keep thinking something like `control is Control`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a case where you don't want to use var.

```
foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
{
    control.Hide();
}
```

does exactly what you want.

Test it if you do not believe.

For other scenarios where you could potentially have a mixed collection, you could do something like

```
foreach (var foo in listOfObjects.OfType<Foo>())
{

}
```

Comment: I did not do this because resharper thought that the only other option for that collection was `Object`.  I assumed (as I indicated in my question) that the values returned by the collection were of type `Object` and could be of different type of classes.

Comment: In this case R# is wrong and Anthong Pegram is right. All objects in the Controls collection will be of type Control, so it's safe to declare the iteration variable as `Control`. The other solutions are just over-complicating something that's really simple.

Comment: The ControlCollection is pre-Generics in C# and is thusly not strongly typed, which is why type inference on var pulls object instead of Control. However, you should be safe to say Control control rather than var control since the collection really only holds controls. Much like if you had an ArrayList containing only ints, you could say (int i in arrayList) even though it technically stores items as objects.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly it.

```
foreach (var control in this.Controls)
{
    if(control is Control) 
    {
        ((Control)control).Hide(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: -1: For C# 3, it's *so* much cleaner to use `var control in this.Controls.OfType<Control>()`

Answer (score 1):

```
Control c = control as Control;
if (c != null)
    c.Hide();
```

or

```
if (control is Control)
    ((Control)control).Hide();
```

Comment: You have them in the wrong order - `as` is preferable to `is`.

Comment: Edited the order, to reflect the fact that 'as' is preferable to 'is'.

Answer (score 1):

Or as an Alternative you could also do

```
foreach(var control in this.Controls.OfType<Control>())
{
  control.Hide();
}
```

Comment: (it is unclear if the OP *knows* that all the items are `Control`s - if not, `OfType` would be better than `Cast`)

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers (confirming your hunch) are probably right.

I have encountered a situation where `Type.IsAssignableFrom` matched what I needed when `is` didn't.  (Unfortunately, I don't remember now what the situation was.)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this:

```
if (control is Control)
    ((Control)control).Hide();
```

or

```
if (control is Control)
    (control as Control).Hide();
```

or if you just want to iterate over the Controls,

```
foreach(var control in this.Controls.Cast<Control>())
    control.Hide();
```

Comment: -1: For each of your three examples, there is a better way to do it. The first two should be an `as` followed by a null check. The last should either use `OfType` instead of `Cast`, or use `foreach(Control control in this.Controls)`, depending on the intended behavior.